# Flutter (Dart): Split the screen into 6 sections, each with one corner in the center

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to split the screen into 6 sections/parts with the following requirements:

- Each section should have a corner in the center of the screen (connected to the centered circle in the example drawing, see below).
- Each section should be connected to the perimeter of the screen.

I want to have a separate GestureDetector in each of these sections.

Does anyone know any good ways to do this with Flutter & Dart?

**example drawing**

[image: Link to example drawing]

Comment: did you try with cliper?

Comment: Do you mean the flutter_custom_clippers? Or ClipPath?

Comment: `ClipPath` is what you need

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Inner circle, I am using [`Container`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) and [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) to place those widgets. And shape is made using [`ClipPath`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html).

> Make use to place the circle button as last stack child, because UI prioritize bottom to top,

Run on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=4ed7b0e9e324296aa42c6c7f29a87d13).

**Paths**

```dart
class BottomCentertPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) => Path()
    ..moveTo(size.width / 4, size.height)
    ..lineTo(size.width / 4 * 3, size.height)
    ..lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}

class BottomLeftPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) => Path()
    ..moveTo(size.width, size.height / 3 * 2)
    ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
    ..lineTo(size.width / 4 * 3, size.height)
    ..lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}

class BottomRightPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) => Path()
    ..moveTo(0, size.height / 3 * 2)
    ..lineTo(0, size.height)
    ..lineTo(size.width / 4, size.height)
    ..lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}

class CenterRighttPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) => Path()
    ..moveTo(size.width, size.height / 3)
    ..lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height / 2)
    ..lineTo(size.width, size.height / 3 * 2);

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}

class CenterLeftPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) => Path()
    ..moveTo(0, size.height / 3)
    ..lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height / 2)
    ..lineTo(0, size.height / 3 * 2);

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}

class TopRightPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) => Path()
    ..moveTo(size.width / 2, 0)
    ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
    ..lineTo(size.width, size.height / 3)
    ..lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}

class TopLeftPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) => Path()
    ..lineTo(size.width / 2, 0)
    ..lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height / 2)
    ..lineTo(0, size.height / 3);

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

**Test Widget**

```dart
class S7venIn1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const S7venIn1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        return Stack(
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                debugPrint("TopLeftPath:");
              },
              child: ClipPath(
                clipper: TopLeftPath(),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.cyanAccent,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                debugPrint("TopRightPath:");
              },
              child: ClipPath(
                clipper: TopRightPath(),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.deepPurple,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                debugPrint("CenterLeftPath:");
              },
              child: ClipPath(
                clipper: CenterLeftPath(),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ClipPath(
              clipper: CenterRighttPath(),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                debugPrint("CenterRighttPath:");
              },
              child: ClipPath(
                clipper: CenterRighttPath(),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.greenAccent,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                debugPrint("BottomRightPath");
              },
              child: ClipPath(
                clipper: BottomRightPath(),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.indigoAccent,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                debugPrint("BottomCentertPath");
              },
              child: ClipPath(
                clipper: BottomCentertPath(),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                debugPrint("BottomLeftPath");
              },
              child: ClipPath(
                clipper: BottomLeftPath(),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.amberAccent,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  debugPrint("Center Widget");
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: constraints.maxWidth * .25,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Play with size on `CustomClipper<Path>`. Check [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html) to learn more about it.

**Result**

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, Yeasin, thanks a lot!