# Slicing a circular container in which each slice behaves like a tab in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I am trying to achieve a circular widget in which each slice represents a tab and having a separation line between each slice coming out from the centre of the circle as shown in the image.

[image: Required View]

I have tried bunch of packages and I found the following package fulfilling the purpose to some extent. https://pub.dev/packages/circular_widgets

I have also tried with Clipping and Custom painting API, but couldn't achieve what i am looking for.

Comment: Use ClipPath Widget with Stack, You can check [Split the screen into 6 sections, each with one corner in the center](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70482988/10157127)

Comment: I was looking for a more dynamic solution than a hard coded one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made custom painter with widgets
I hope this help you

```
class CircleCustomPainer extends CustomPainter {
  var count = 6;
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.red;
    Paint paint1 = Paint();
    paint1.color = Colors.white;
    paint1.strokeWidth = 4;
    paint1.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    canvas.drawCircle(
        Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2), size.height / 2, paint);

    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      var o = (2 * i * math.pi) / count;
      var x = 150 * math.cos(o) + (size.width / 2);
      var y = 150 * math.sin(o) + (size.height / 2);
      path.lineTo(x, y);
      path.moveTo(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint1);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

this is widget creator for menu

```
Widget getWidgets(int count, Size size) {
  List<Widget> list = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var o = (2 * i * math.pi) / count;
    o = o + ((360 / count) / 57.2958) / 2;
    var x = (size.width / 3) * math.cos(o) + (size.width / 2);
    var y = (size.width / 3) * math.sin(o) + (size.height / 2);

    list.add(Positioned.fromRect(
      rect: Rect.fromCenter(center: Offset(x, y), height: 60, width: 60),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: 60,
            height: 60,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }

  return Container(
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Stack(
      children: list,
    ),
  );
}
```

you can used like this

```
SizedBox(
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              CustomPaint(
                size: Size(300, 300),
                painter: CircleCustomPainer(),
              ),
              Center(child: getWidgets(6, Size(300, 300)))
            ],
          ),
        )
```

I will probably create a youtube video for that

Comment: Thank you, this was the exact solution i was looking for.